# ruby with csv file add next line automatically

Tags: csv

```
def supplier_registeration

    print "Registration form :"
    print "\nName :"
    name = gets.chomp.downcase
    print "User Name :"
    user_name = gets.chomp.downcase
    print "Password :"
    password = gets.chomp.downcase
    print "contact :"
    contact = gets.chomp.to_i
    print "address :"
    address = gets.chomp.downcase 

    CSV.open("source/supplier.csv", "wb") do |csv|
      csv << ["name", "user name", "password", "contact", "address"]
      csv << [name, user_name, password, contact, address]
    end
    print "Registration successfully..!\n"
    supplier

end
```

This method writes to the CSV file, but on the next registration entry, my file rewrites the initial data. How do I append user input to the next line automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer for above question

```
  'headers = ['name','user name','password','contact','address']
  CSV.open('source/consumer_list.csv', 'a+', {force_quotes: true}) do |csv|
    csv << headers if csv.count.eql? 0
    csv << [name, user_name, password, contact, address]
  end'
```